# Which graph partitioning algorithm can solve this problem?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry

[image]

**In brief:**
Here I have a cyclic graph above. I want to partition the graph vertices into `3` clusters. (With the mindset of cluster-wise "load balancing") 
*Constraint*: All the vertices in each cluster should be directly connected.
*Goal*: the deviance of the cluster-sums should be as small as possible. (In other words, the sum of loads of all clusters should be as balanced as possible.)


**Examples:**
*An infeasible example*: `ADG` `CE` `BF`. Reason: The vertices are not directly connected within each cluster.
*A feasible but bad example*: `AB` `CD` `EFG`. Reason: The load is not optimally balanced (Difference `14` `14` `59` is too large).
*The optimal solution*: `ABCD` `EF` `G`. Reason: the difference among three cluster-sums (`28` `29` `30` respectively) is the smallest.

Which algorithm can get the optimal solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is $\text{NP}$-hard. To see why, consider the version of the 3-Partition problem where we're given multiset $ X = \{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{3n}\}$ of $3n$ nonnegative integers, and we need to decide whether $X$ can be partitioned into three disjoint multisets with the same sum each. Clearly, an instance $X = \{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{3n}\}$ of the 3-Partition problem can be translated in polynomial time into a complete graph $G = \langle V, E \rangle$, where $V = \{ v_i\}_{i\in [3n]}$  and for each $v_i$, we have that the weight $w(v_i) = x_i$. That is, we view the integers as $3n$ vertices, and every two vertices are connected with an edge. Obviously, a balanced 3-clustering of $G$ corresponds to an appropriate 3-partition of the multiset $X$.